# Using "each do" to output a list, how to skip the last comma?

Tags: ruby

Ruby beginner:

Outputting a list using

```
each do
```

When I print the list, It iterates the puts"," the same amount of times as the list, because, well that's what I told it to do. How to I tell it to not to put the comma the last time/skip the last comma and put a question mark instead? Sample code below:

```
contacts = {
    "Freddy" => {
    "phone" => 666,
    "tiktok" => "asdf",
    "instagram" => "def",
    "email" => "in.your@dreams"
  }
}
name = "Freddy"

print "We know these things about #{name}:"
    contacts[name].each do |key, value|
        print " #{key}"
        print "," 
    end
    print "?\n"
```

Desired output is:
We know these things about Freddy: phone, tictok, instagram, email?

not

We know these things about Freddy: phone, tictok, instagram, email,? (get rid of last comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining the keys with a comma would be much easier that trying to skip the last comma in an `each do` loop:

```
print contacts[name].keys().join(", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to form the full string using *string
interpolation* and then *put-s* it:

```
puts "We know know these things about %s: %s?" %
  [name, contacts[name].keys.join(', ')]
```

displays

```
We know know these things about Freddy: phone, tiktok, instagram, email?
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for string formatting directives.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `*` ruby sugar syntax:

```rb
print contacts[name].keys * ", "
```